# How to debug through included library in c++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

In general, I want to learn how I can look at line by line execution of any C++ compiled library. Usually when we compile any library, we get its include folder (where all header files are placed) and lib folder (where library is placed). And we use the library by including its header files in our programs.

I am interested in learning the workflow of library http://www.cryptopp.com/

Its source code is available in https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp

Specifically I am interested in going through the work flow of this library - crypto++.

I have installed it using homebrew, although it can be installed using source code as well.

I am using the library in my Xcode project. I have added the library libcrytopp.a and using the header files to execute various library. Also, I am familier with terminal.

Whenever I set a break point in the code and go to debugger mode and any line comes where the library is being called, I go to the line of header file where the function is. But I want to go to the line in the source code and see execution line by line. for example, I want to see in des.cpp in the source how the code executes line by line.

Is there any way I can see it?

Comment: To debug at the source level you need to have compiled for debugging and you need to be able to present your source to the debugger. The easiest way to do this in your case might be to just include the library sources in your project directly, rather than linking against the library. As to how to do any of this, it's way too broad for this site.

Comment: can you share any link?